# Jquery Dialog Scrollbar solution

Tags: jquery, browser, scrollbar

I have a result-set in my dialog box that I would like to scroll (if the results span larger than the actual dialog height. I am doing this via the following method: 
$("#'||the_result_set_id||'").css({overflow:"scroll"});

This doesn't seem to be consistent with IE versus Mozilla. Is there a better solution for this, where I can get scrollars to appear for both browsers? Currently, the scrollbars are not appearing in IE.

Comment: I did find this post: http://www.mail-archive.com/jquery-ui@googlegroups.com/msg08300.html

However, changing the DOCTYPE is not an option for me, due to the way our programs are setup. Is there another solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

if you set the height of the dialog, it should add scrollbars as needed.

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
  height: 100
});
```

Sample: http://jsbin.com/ixipa3/2